# Wordpresss admin too many redirects

Tags: wordpress

What could be causing a "too many redirects" error in my WordPress website? The backend broke with this issue, few days ago, I do not know what happened.
I cannot leave the value of siteurl as http:/url because of security issue and also because it causes mixed content error

I have tried updating siteurl to HTTPS in the database options table, it works, but changing it back to HTTP leads to a breakdown again. I have deactivated all plugins it did not help, and the .htaccess file seems fine. I tried removing .htaccess it did not work, I uploaded and new .htaccess from a working site still did not work

.htaccess
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tp7vb.png)

Comment: can you share your .htaccess? (don't forget to obfuscate sensitive values). Your problem could be caused by a rule that tries to redirect `http` to `https`. This kind of redirection is common when people migrated existing sites to HTTPS

Comment: Sorry I have been away from computer for 2 days as requested by my doctor. Let me send it upload it

Comment: # BEGIN WordPress
# The directives (lines) between "BEGIN WordPress" and "END WordPress" are
# dynamically generated, and should only be modified via WordPress filters.
# Any changes to the directives between these markers will be overwritten.
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteBase /e-startups/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /e-startups/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress

Comment: Can you please edit the question (using the edit link under the question) to add it, this is hard to read in a comment

Comment: I have added an image

Comment: click on .httacces bellow the question

Comment: I see no issue with this htaccess, it is the minimal wordpress one, do you have other htaccess files in upper levels of the folders of the server? Also it's not clear why you wanted to use HTTP instead of HTTPS, and if only the backend broke or if the frontend broke too..

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to resolve the issue by appending a fix to wp-config.php. I have attached a screenshot of the part that contains the code:

[image]